# Getting a value from MongoDB using ExpressJS

Tags: mongodb, express

I'm trying to single fetch a value from my database.
I have a collection named: randoms
Model's Name: Random

Inside the collection, I have one object and with a name field. I want to retrieve that value of 'name' and display it in my console.

The result in the console should be: 'TestName' only.

This has been my approach:

```
Random.find({}, (err, randoms) => {
    if(err) throw err
    // console.log(randoms)
    res.render('entries', console.log(randoms.name))
})
```

The console displays the result: undefined.

Here's the database.

[image]

If I console.log(randoms) instead of console.log(randoms.name) I get the result:

```
[{ 
    _id: 5e256c819f972c268493488c,
    name: 'TestName',
    defination: 'Home page paragraph text',
    count: 2,
    __v: 0
}]
```

so that means the connection is alright.

Comment: It seems like your trying to access the object instead of looking at the object in the array? Try randoms[0].name

Comment: @Dennington-bear yeah that was it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

db.collection.find returns a Cursor which is A pointer to the result set of a query. Clients can iterate through a cursor to retrieve results.

yourCollection.find().forEach(function(item){})